# Xampp Unknown Error When I Try to Run Project Written with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I downloaded, installed Xampp 1.8.0 and 1.5.0 (For different versions of PHP). They both work with HelloWorld program but when i try to run a CodeIgniter project it gives this error. [image: Error]

It says "There Had Been a Problem In Database" and "Connection cannot be established with configurations provided by database server ". Checked everywhere (CodeIgniter, Xampp, Wamp also) everysite and every version almost. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to your `application` folder for `codeigniter`, there will be a `config` folder which contains a file called `database.php`. This file contains the database connectivity for your application.

Something like this:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
|
| For complete instructions please consult the 'Database Connection'
| page of the User Guide.
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|   ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
|   ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
|   ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
|   ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
|   ['dbdriver'] The database type. ie: mysql.  Currently supported:
                 mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8
|   ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
|                to the table name when using the  Active Record class
|   ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
|   ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
```

**IF** you are using a database in your application make sure that the connection settings in this file are correct.

If you are not using a database in your application, chances are that the database connectivity is being autoloaded, which is causing you application to fail. In that case go to `autoload.php` file, which is in same folder and check for the following lines:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
| or in your application/libraries folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

If `database` is being auto-loaded, remove it from the array and your application should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my problem i was checking out the code so the database username etc. was different thank you again.